# qt executing code on creating a form

Tags: c++, qt

How to perform a code on creation of the main form? Say, I have to call a simple
`MessageBox(0, L"Hello World!", L"Debug", MB_OK)` that will be called after the form's creation but before its appearing on screen. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a new **class** that inherits from this *form* (`QWidget`? `QMainWindow`?). Then, on the **constructor** of the class, execute:

```
MessageBox(0, L"Hello World!", L"Debug", MB_OK)
```